# Can i access the value of a variable of one method in another method if i have declared it as a member variable of the class in java?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

Can I access the value of a variable of one method in another method if I have declared it as a member variable of the class in java?

```
class xxx{
    public int[]yyy;
    private boolean handleMessage{
        ...
        int[]yyy = (int[]) msg.obj;
    }
    private zzz{
        int[]sval= yyy;
    }
}
```

Does the value of `yyy` carry over to `sval`?

Answer (score 4):

No, that creates a new variable in the method scope that dies once the method ends. The class level member is is still null.

What you need to do is change

```
int[]yyy = (int[]) msg.obj;
```

to

```
yyy = (int[]) msg.obj;
```

But remeber that, if `handleMessage` is not called, and `zzz` is, then `sval` will still be null

Answer (score 1):

> Can i access the value of a variable of one method in another method
>   if i have declared it as a member variable of the class in java?

No, you can't. The method local variable `yyy` has a scope inside the method it's declared. You can't access it outside of that method in any means.

And the instance variable `yyy` don't have any relation to the method local variable `yyy`. Both are two different.

Answer (score 0):

You are right... that is the purpose of member variables.

There is a small bug in your listing however.
You have defined two different yyy references one at class level and one at method level.

Your assignment should be like this (without creating a new variable again in the method):

```
yyy = (int[]) msg.obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you create another variable `yyy` inside the method handleMessage(), it has the method scope. It will not carried to outside of the method unless you pass it to other method manually.

In case, if you have just assigned value to `yyy` inside method handleMessage() instead of creating one, you would get the value in `yyy` assigned to `sval` like in following code.

```
class xxx{
    public int[]yyy;
    private boolean handleMessage{
        ...
        yyy = (int[]) msg.obj; 
    }
    private zzz{
        int[]sval= yyy;
    }
}
```